# Session is not get expired in Chrome & FF with 'event.clientY'

Tags: javascript, java, struts

On my close of browser session is not get expired in Chrome & FF, from  debugging I have found that  'event.clientY' is not working. In IE it is working fine.  session relation code is there in java.

```
<html> 
    <body onbeforeunload="CloseSess()">

    function CloseSess() {
                    if (event.clientY < 0) {
                                            location.href=location.protocol+"//"+location.host+"${ctx}/logoutpage.jsp";
                    }
                }

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What's `event` here? It's not defined anywhere. Are you talking about a mouse event? Where Y < 0?! What are you trying to do?

Comment: After closing browser session is not expiring.